# Counting number of time any song has been played in last few days

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

Actually, I'm trying to find-out what genre of song I listen to most. To do this, I need to find out what songs were played in last "time constraint" and how many times? VLC media player (under window 7) was my choice of weapon all the time, but I couldn't find any way to track it. How can I? Any Idea

Is it even possible, by some command from command-prompt or some 'trick'?

P.S : I know, its an evil idea. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows Media Player tracks Play Counts AFAIK. In the Expanded Tiles or Details view add the Play Count column and see the stats.

Or else you can use a better audio player like foobar2000, along with the [Playback Statistics component](http://www.foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_playcount). You can check out all the fields supported [here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Components/Playback_Statistics_v3.x_%28foo_playcount%29).

If your files are tagged properly, it *may* also be possible to use this component's DB somehow to directly list the genres in order of playback. For that I recommend asking in the foobar forum.